# Scary BizTalk receive location bug

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010, azureservicebus

I just noticed a major bug (Unless im missing something) in BizTalk connected to a servicebus queue using the WCF-Custom adapter.

I noticed a message had not reached BizTalk from the queue so i checked that the receive location was running in BizTalk which it was.

However i could see the messages getting stacked in the queue.

BizTalk provided no warning or error-message and there were no indication from BizTalk that the receive location had lost the connection to the queue.

When i restarted the Receive location i could see the messagecount drop down to zero in the servicebus management console so it seems like BizTalk lost the connection without even noticing it.

If im not missing something important, this is a very serious bug in BizTalk since it blocks the flow without any warning or noticable reason.

I have 2 colleagues who have also run into the problem however i think they were using the sftp-adapter.

Does anybody else have any experience with this behavior?

I tried googling it but found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

How are you receiving the message using the WCF-Custom adapter?  I am presuming you are using some custom code since it doesn't work out of the box.

Which BizTalk Server are you using?  There is no SFTP adapter in BizTalk Server.

We have recently announced BizTalk Server 2010 R2 CTP, where we will be providing a first class adapter for Service Bus Queues/Topics.  We would like you to try that out and provide feedback on that.  We also would like to understand how you are using this.

Comment: I am using the netMessagingBinding and transportClientEndpointBehavior found in the Microsoft.BizTalk.dll.
We have had lots of trouble with messages disappearing when the queues have been inactive for a while but those problems are solved with an application keeping the queues "Alive" with frequent dummy-messages.
About the sftp-adapter im not sure, i just repeated what i thougt i heard.
We are using BizTalk 2010 but its probably not R2 CTP.
I will look into that.
Thanks a lot for the reply!